# Is every submodule of a free module of finite rank finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Surely it is true? But somehow I can't think of a way to prove it. Let's assume the ring is commutative with identity.

Comment: Every submodule of a free module of finite rank is finitely generated if and only if the ring is noetherian.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take $R = \mathbb{F_p}[X_i:i\in \omega]$ and $M = (X_i: i\in \omega)$. Then $R$ is free but $M$ is not finitely generated.

Answer (score 5):

Consider $R=(\mathbb{Z}_p)^{\mathbb{N}}$ the product of ring of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as many times as the naturals, now $M=(\mathbb{Z}_p)^{(\mathbb{N})}$ the coproduct of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as many times as the naturals. This counter example works for any $K$ field, but is easy to see when p=2. R is free of rank 1.

Answer (score 2):

Now I realize that it had better be NOT true, otherwise there would be no need to talk about finitely presented modules.